# Using sass source maps in web-starter-kit

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools

i started with the [google web starter kit](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit) template today and i was wondering if i could watch the sass files while debugging. Now i only see the compiled components.css and main.css. I did enable source-maps but apparently you can only see the compiled version.

many tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem.  The following article from Google helped me:
[Chrome Dev Tools CSS Preprocessors](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors)

Specifically, check your gulpfile.js to make sure that the rubySass task has source maps enabled like so:

```
   gulp.task('styles:scss', function () {
  return gulp.src(['app/styles/**/*.scss', '!app/styles/components/components.scss'])
    .pipe($.rubySass({
      style: 'expanded',
      precision: 10,
      loadPath: ['app/styles'],
      sourcemap: true
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer('last 1 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'styles:scss'}));
});
```

The above causes the css source maps to be generated.  Next, I turned on CSS source maps in the Chrome Dev Tools settings.  Lastly, I created a Chrome Workspace - which was mentioned in the above Chrome Dev Tools documentation.

More information on Workspaces can be found here:
[Chrome Dev Tools Workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces)

Comment: tnx for your reply. I did manage to see the sass files in dev tools. Tnx. However, editing them in dev tools directly doesn't work. Should it?